# How to Make middleware that validates a Date using Express

Tags: express

i want to Create a middleware function that will check if a movie's release date is older than 2000. If it is, return the message "We only accept movies after 2000".

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example of how you can create a middleware function,** [I assumed the format of your POST request, but we can edit this based on more specifics]

```
const express = require("express");

const PORT = 9900;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const validateMovie = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.release < 2000) {
    res.status(400).send("We can only accept movies after 2000");
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.post("/movies", validateMovie, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Movie added!");
});

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  console.log("Try at localhost:9900/movies");
});
```

Comment: That Is Good Answer But the format of Date Is Like 03-march-2022 , that is Why i Want to Help Me